# keep track of random numbers in java

Tags: java

How do I keep tracking the value of `randomNumber`  and then use it else where. In the code below every time I click the mouse I get random number between 0 and 10.

If I click 3 times and I get for example the values 1,6 and 7 how do I keep track of these 3 values and use them somewhere else. I want to store them in variable like, `int firstClick=?;`,`int secondClick=?;`and `int thirdClick=?;` how do i do that.

```
void mousePressed(){
int randomNumber= int(random(11));
System.out.println(randomNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

step 1 : create an arraylist of integers

step 2 : generate random number

step 3 : store random no in arraylist

step 4 : compare this arraylist after generating new random no

step 5 : if new random no doesn't exist in arraylist , use it , store this no in arraylist

step 6 : if random no does exist in arraylist , generate another random no

```
//global variable
List<Integer> randomNumberArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

then

```
void mousePressed() 

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        {
            int temp = generateRandomNumber();
            if (!randomNumberArray.contains(temp)) 
            {
                randomNumberArray.add(temp);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(randomNumberArray);
    }

    public int generateRandomNumber() 
    {
        Random randomNumber = new Random();
        return randomNumber.nextInt(20);
    }
```

or you can simply use a Set

```
void mousePressed() 

    {
       Set<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        int temp = generateRandomNumber();
        //System.out.println(temp);
        mySet.add(temp);
    }
    System.out.println(mySet);
    }
```

Comment: How do I store a random number in array ?

Answer (score 3):

Use an `ArrayList` somewhere in your class:

```
public class MyClass {

    private ArrayList<Integer> randomNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    public void mousePressed() {
        int randomNumber= int(random(11));
        randomNumbers.add(randomNumber);
        System.out.println(randomNumber);
    }

    public void listNumbers() {
        for (Integer number : randomNumbers) {
            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }

}
```

This way, you can keep track of any number of mouse clicks and the numbers generated by them. You don't have to assign each individual number to a specific `int` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
final List<Integer> randomNumbers= new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
   randomNumbers.add(random(11));
}
// get first one
int i = randomNumbers.get(0);
```

Comment: ~ final && implementation a little off OPs example

Answer (score 0):

This will require a variable with a scope beyond the method you are dealing with.  Some options are:

```
// Have the random number be the return value of the method:
public int mousePressed() { return int(random(11)); }

// Have the random number be assigned to a class scoped variable:
static int someN;
public void mousePressed() { someN = int(random(11)); }
```

Obviously this will need to be extended to have three (or however many) values assigned/returned.  The Object `ArrayList<Integer>` could come in handy here.